# MongoDB :: Order Search result depend on search condition

Tags: mongodb, search

I have a data

```
[{ "name":"BS",
  "keyword":"key1",
  "city":"xyz"
},
{ "name":"AGS",
  "keyword":"Key2",
  "city":"xyz1"
},
{ "name":"QQQ",
  "keyword":"key3",
  "city":"xyz"
},
{ "name":"BS",
  "keyword":"Keyword",
  "city":"city"
}]
```

and i need to search records which have name= "BS" OR keyword="key2" with the help of query

```
db.collection.find({"$OR" : [{"name":"BS"}, {"keyword":"Key2"}]});
```

These records i need in the sequence

```
[{ "name":"BS",
  "keyword":"key1",
  "city":"xyz"
},
{ "name":"BS",
  "keyword":"Keyword",
  "city":"city"
},
{ "name":"AGS",
  "keyword":"Key2",
  "city":"xyz1"
}]
```

but i am getting in following sequences:

```
[{ "name":"BS",
  "keyword":"key1",
  "city":"xyz"
},
{ "name":"AGS",
  "keyword":"Key2",
  "city":"xyz1"
},
{ "name":"BS",
  "keyword":"Keyword",
  "city":"city"
}]
```

Please provide some suggestion i am stuck with this problem since 2 days.
 Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The order of results returned by MongoDB is not guaranteed unless you explicitly sort your data using the `sort` function. For smaller datasets you maybe "lucky" in the sense that the results are always returned in the same order, however, for bigger datasets and in particular when you have sharded Mongo clusters this is very unlikely. As proposed by Yathish you need to explicitly order your results using the `sort` function. Based on the suggested output, it seems you want to sort by name in descending order so I have set the sorting flag to `-1` for the field `name`.

```
db.collection.find({"$or" : [{"name":"BS"}, {"keyword":"Key2"}]}).sort({"name" : -1});
```

If you need a more complex sorting algorithm as specified in your comment, you can convert your results to a Javascript array and create a custom sort function. This sort function will first list documents with a `name` equal to "BS" and then documents containing the `keyword` "Key2"

```
db.data.find({
    "$or": [{
        "name": "BS"
    }, {
        "keyword": "Key2"
    }]
}).toArray().sort(function(doc1, doc2) {
    if (doc1.name == "BS" && doc2.keyword == "Key2") {
        return -1
    } else if (doc2.name == "BS" && doc1.keyword == "Key2") {
        return 1
    } else {
        return doc1.name < doc2.name
    }
});
```

Comment: i can't do sorting because my scenario is i need data that contain firstly all records which have name BS and then records which have keyword key2 in a same array and condition may be more then two.

Comment: I have extended my post to include your custom sorting requirements.